# Console says JavaScript array is undefined, but I'm able to log its contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have an array, `gradesArray`, which I'm able to see with `console.log(gradesArray)` within my program, but when I go to access it typing `gradesArray` or `gradesArray.length` or something similar into the (Chrome) console, I get `ReferenceError: gradesArray is not defined`.

Here's the jQuery I use to fill the array with `Grade` objects:

```
$(document).on('click', '#savegrades', saveGrade);

function saveGrade() {                     // grabbing data from a form
    var studentClass = currentClass;
    var studentName = currentStudent;
    var dateStamp = $(this).parents('#gradingform').children('#date').val().replace(/-/g, "");
    var teamwork = parseInt( $(this).parents('#gradingform').children('#teamwork').val() );
    var participation = parseInt( $(this).parents('#gradingform').children('#participation').val() );
    var punctuality = parseInt( $(this).parents('#gradingform').children('#punctuality').val() );
    var professionalism = parseInt( $(this).parents('#gradingform').children('#professionalism').val() );
    var timemanagement = parseInt( $(this).parents('#gradingform').children('#timemanagement').val() );

    var newGrade = new Grade(studentClass, studentName, dateStamp, teamwork, participation,         // create new Grade object from form values
                                punctuality, professionalism, timemanagement);

    alert('class: ' + newGrade.studentClass + ', name: ' + newGrade.studentName + ', date: ' + newGrade.dateStamp + ', teamwork: ' + newGrade.teamwork + ', participation: ' + newGrade.participation + ', punctuality: ' + newGrade.punctuality + ', professionalism: ' + newGrade.professionalism + ', time management: ' + newGrade.timemanagement + ', total: ' + newGrade.total);

    gradesArray.push(newGrade);
    console.log(gradesArray);
}
```

After this code runs, that `console.log(gradesArray)` bit works just fine, giving me a nice array of Grade objects. But when I type `gradesArray` into the console, I get a reference error telling me that the variable is undefined. Also, later in the program, I try to use `if (typeof gradesArray != 'undefined')`, but the function doesn't fire.

What's the deal? The browser will log the array if I ask it to from the .js file, but it won't if I ask it to right from the console; and, even after I've filled it with objects, it's still undefined, even though they're showing up in the console.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you forgot brackets
saveGrade()

Comment: Where is your `gradesArray` originally declared?

Comment: @TimurShahbanov: Wrong.

Comment: I declared the array at the very beginning of the document ready function.

Comment: Problem solved--just forgot to make it global by declaring the array outside of the `$(document).ready(function() {...});`. Must be tired. Thanks to all.

Comment: remember to check the accepted answer.  Click the check mark symbol by the one you approve.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. If more than one answer is right you just check the first one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not copy all code; your code is wrapped in another function (`$(function () {})`?) that contains the var statement for gradesArray. Because it is not a global variable, it cannot be inspected from the console. Easiest is to put the var statement outside your $():

```
var gradesArray = []
$(function () { ... });
```

Comment: Yes! Solved. It's wrapped in the document ready function. Good call.

Comment: Of course it was wrapped into `$(...)`, so it's not available to console, +1 ^^

Answer (score 0):

By the time you log in the console, `gradesArray` is out of scope. Try declaring it in global scope if you need it there.